# How to solve this 7x8 grid with partially and completely filled squares?

Tags: visual

I've tried looking at the paper from different angles, and nothing is jumping out at me. I'm not sure what to try next.
[image: 7*8 grid with partially and completely filled squares.]

Thanks!

Comment: Looks identical to this page in Martin Gardner book https://books.google.ca/books?id=oSM0gcVKzoEC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=shown+above+is+a+hidden+greeting&source=bl&ots=L1QXX061ld&sig=8b4vjXV2TviQiOqPRhLu1a2B6eU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kkXLVP6yEoG3ogSR64D4Ag&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=shown%20above%20is%20a%20hidden%20greeting&f=false

Comment: I saw this in one of my 8th grade geometry textbooks a decade or so ago.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The answer is:

> HELLO - just compress the vertical dimension like this:
>  [image]